# "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" after ~30 seconds

Tags: c#, wcf

I have WCF service hosted on IIS7 and it has started "forcibly closing connections".

Eg. When request is sent, application starts processing it and in a mean time connection gets closed with following exception(s)

`An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to https://############/#########.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.`

`Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.`

`An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`

The endpoint is using SSL (TLS1.0).

If the request lasts shorter than 30 seconds, the response is appropriately retrieved, but if the request lasts longer than 30 seconds, the connection gets forcibly closed (request continues executing on the endpoint and completes, but the response is never retrieved).

Comment: Did you configured the timeouts for you binding?

Comment: Yes `<binding name="####" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00">`

Comment: On both sides? The client binding timeouts needs to be configured as well. 30 seconds sounds like a unconfigured timeout. If the client is configured, too. Try a empty method on your service that waits longer than 30 seconds to answer. If the issue consists, its a timout problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the maxReceivedMessageSize and and set it to the maximum number of bytes you want to support.And also receiveTimeout based on your requirement .
Example :

```
         <binding name="Your Binding Name" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="" />
```

Comment: Bindings are configured `<binding name="####" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00">`

Comment: Y downvoted ? . Did u mentioned anything about binding config of  maxReceivedMessageSize and receiveTimeout in your question?

Comment: fine.What kind of request you perform with the service?. If its read High volume of  data from service,  try to increase the maxReceivedMessageSize .

Comment: The response would retrieve several flags, which should not cause the message size issue

Comment: Check EventViewer log in Server and Client. there we may find any useful information.